# Inserting random data in PostgreSQL but with choices

Tags: postgresql

So I'm inserting a data for 3k columns but I want them to have random set of inserts to be inserted.
For example:

('ATMOUTOFSERVICE','ATMBEINGSERVICE','NETWORKCONNECTIONLOST','BLACKSCREEN')

Is there any possible way that i can insert them in my columns randomly but just within those choices?

Comment: You can't have a table with 3000 columns. Did you mean 3000 **rows**?

Comment: Must it be a pure Postgres solution? If not, you could write a short Python, Java etc. program creating and executing `INSERT` statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
insert into target_table (some_column)
select case (random() * 3 + 1)::int
          when 1 then 'ATMOUTOFSERVICE'
          when 2 then 'ATMBEINGSERVICE'
          when 3 then 'NETWORKCONNECTIONLOST'
          when 'BLACKSCREEN'
       end
from generate_series(1,...);
```

Or use an array:

```
insert into target_table (some_column)
select (array['ATMOUTOFSERVICE',
              'ATMBEINGSERVICE',
              'NETWORKCONNECTIONLOST',
              'BLACKSCREEN'])[(random() * 3 + 1)::int]
from generate_series(1, ...);
```

Comment: can i use this on UPDATE query?

Comment: UPDATE dashboard.event 
SET event_description = (
select (array['CAM OUT OF SERVICE',
              'CAM BEING SERVICE',
              'NETWORK CONNECTION LOST',
              'BLACKSCREEN',
    'BNA DEVICE ERROR'])[(random() * 3 + 2)::int]
from generate_series(1, 5));

i keep using this code but it won't update the null values

Comment: Get rid of the select and generate_series: `SET event_description = (array['ATMOUTOFSERVICE',
              'ATMBEINGSERVICE',
              'NETWORKCONNECTIONLOST',
              'BLACKSCREEN'])[(random() * 3 + 1)::int]`